# Primary manufacturers of picture tubes for early monitors

Tags: hardware, history, crt-monitor

Which companies were the most important manufacturers of picture tubes for monitors (both monochrome and color) in the seventies and eighties? That is, it's easy enough to find lists of monitors by nominal manufacturer of the model (IBM, DEC, Commodore etc), but it's not as easy to find which companies typically were the actual manufacturers of the picture tubes.

Comment: The same as for televisions; EMI, Philips, etc.

Comment: @Chenmunka  ... and of course Sony (you could always tell a Sony tube because the RGB phosphors were aligned horizontally across the screen rather than in a triangular arrangement - like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinitron#/media/File:Trinitron-bars-detail-enlarged.jpg)

Comment: Back then there was a phletoria of component manufacturers. Next to each country had one or more. Heck, even in high wage countries like Germany CRTs where produced well into the late 80s, early 90s. This question can't be realy answered as it's way to broad. Mabe specifying which Brand and/or country you're looking for, but even then, what consists 'most important'? In the US, or in Europe, or in Asia, or maybe behind the iron curtain?

Comment: @Raffzahn That's useful information already, but to be more specific, say the aggregate of all monitors sold in the U.S., and most important in terms of ranking in dollar sales.

Comment: Quite likely, the exact same part number was used as a *color* picture tube in computer displays and domestic TVs. They were both just analog displays with the same 4:3 aspect ratio. So the tube manufacturer would have no particular reason to even save the data to answer the question. "Green screen" *mono* displays were limited to the computer market, and other specialist equipment (radar, etc) so that part of the question might be answerable.

Comment: I don't see how this question is any more broad than this one:  https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/639/how-long-will-floppy-disks-maintain-data-integrity   +1 from me.

Comment: If you have to make your own list: Ball, a glass company famous for its canning jars, also made CRT display tubes.

Comment: @alephzero That doesn't sound right. The critical difference that made domestic TVs unsuitable for use as monitors was that they didn't display a sharp enough picture for 80-column text. That was why monitors as a separate entity were necessary.

Comment: I was mostly familiar with Ball monochrome monitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know links as answers are frowned upon. But this official document called "Color Picture Tubes from Canada, Japan, the Republic of Korea, and Singapore" by an US commission has more on both US and foreign producers of CRTs in the 80s than you ever want to know :)

https://www.usitc.gov/publications/701_731/pub2046.pdf

Comment: Quoting the list of the US producers as an example of the information provided in the document would be helpful.

Comment: This leaves out quite a lot of the world.  It is a partial answer at best.  Also, as you say, it is a link.  Please add some details within the post.